# Changing to datetime picker from datepicker

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I was previously using Datepicker.js and I've now changed over to use datetimepicker, otherwise known as tempus dominus.

I switched out my input and div and I also changed the CDN script and the JS script function but I'm having some issues.

My site shows the input field and calendar icon in the modal but when I click the icon it doesn't bring up the calendar to select date and time.

Also, I'm using this to populate with an  array value before hand that shows expiration dates so In the instance that there are multiple items with expiration dates, I need the datetimepicker to show for each one so I may have one picker or I may have multiple.

Is there a certain way I should change this to not only get my calendar to load, but also have it working for multiple instances?

```
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/locale/af.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.0-alpha14/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js" type="text/javascript" > 
</script>
</head>

<h6>Set New Expiration: </h6>
<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
  <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1"/>
    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
      <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.0-alpha14/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
      $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: did you forget to add jquery?

Comment: iT's in my code, I just didn't add it here. adding it now just for reference, my bad

Comment: do you see any console errors in your env?

Comment: I got this:
tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Tempus Dominus Bootstrap4's requires moment.js. Moment.js must be included before Tempus Dominus Bootstrap4's JavaScript.

I just added the CDN above the TD script but it's still showing the error

Comment: would you mind putting exactly what you have now in your example above?

Comment: No problem, it's all up to date now

Comment: I believe you are including the moment.js locale configuration, not moment.js itself.

Comment: You are correct @chakeda, just added the actual .js file and it is now showing the calendar. However, it's set outside of the input box, as opposed to popping up when hitting the icon

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: small improvement, but prob won't fix your issue. include this moment.js instead of the one you have `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js`

Comment: I am only getting Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> now

Comment: So now the field is blank, if I hit the calendar icon it fills the box with today's date and time and the calendar popup is blank